# What are the order types of computable pseudo-ordinals with no c.e. descending chains?

Tags: logic, order-theory, computability, ordinals, well-orders

The notion of a “computable pseudo-ordinal”, i.e. a computable linearly ordered set with no hyperarithmetical descending chains, is an old one going back to Stephen Kleene.  Joe Harrison wrote the [definitive paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1968-131-02/S0002-9947-1968-0244049-7/S0002-9947-1968-0244049-7.pdf) on them in 1968, showing that any such linear order is either well-ordered or has order type $\omega_1^{CK}(1+\eta)+\alpha$ for some computable ordinal $\alpha$, where $\eta$ is the order type of the rationals.

My question is, what are the possible order types of a computable linear order with no computable enumerable descending chains?  I’m guessing that any such linear order either has no hyperarithmetical descending chains or has order type $\omega_1^{CK}(1+\eta+1)+something$, I’m just not sure what the “something” is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every infinite c.e. set has an infinite computable subset, "no c.e. descending chain" is the same as "no computable descending chain." And almost every linear order which has a computable copy in the first place has a computable copy with no descending chain. For example, it's a standard finite injury construction (in Ash/Knight I think) to build a computable copy of $\omega+\omega^*$ with no computable descending sequence.

(On the other hand there are non-examples; for instance, every computable copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ will have a computable descending sequence.)

---

Incidentally, you may be interested in Watnik's [*A generalization of Tennenbaum's theorem on effectively finite recursive linear orderings*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2274189). Watnik classifies the computable linear orders $L$ which have a computable copy $M\cong L$ with no computable descending *or ascending* sequence. (Note that Watnik talks about subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ as concrete examples of linear orders.)

Comment: Let me ask you this: suppose we restrict our attention to linear orders with order type of the form $\omega_1^{CK}(1+\eta+1)+something$.  Does that constrain how many order types you can get, or can the “something” be almost anything?  I’m just trying to make an analogy with the Harrison result.

Comment: I posted my follow up question on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/448551/5017